# How can I send an wxImage through wxSocket in c++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How can I send a wxImage through TCP wxSocket in c++?
Should I convert the wxImage to a wxString or can it be directly send over?
In that case how do I convert a wxImage tobe a wxString?

Answer (score 1):

You have direct access to the image data via its `GetData()` member, so you could just send it directly, at least if you have an image without alpha. However in practice, compressing it first would probably be a good idea as uncompressed images are huge. You could either use [zlib compression](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_zlib_output_stream.html) or, perhaps simpler, write the image in PNG or JPEG format to a memory buffer and send this buffer instead.

Converting the image to a string would be possible too but highly suboptimal.

Comment: How to send a wxImage in c++ to python? Can you give me an example? I used this code to do it but I always can not read it out properly: unsigned char *imageData = wxImage1.GetData();
 int imageSize = wxImage1.GetWidth() * wxImage1.GetHeight() * 3; m_sock->Write(wxImage1, imageSize);

Comment: You should pass `imageData`, not `wxImage`, to `Write()`. If you already do and this was just a typo, then this part seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Hai wxImage::GetData() return unsigned char* so you can easily send image as a string.Don't forget to send image width&height, this two attributes must need for again converting data into image.

Comment: Do I need to send the width&height before I send the unsigned char*? How Can you get the size of the data when writing to the socket? I used this: unsigned char *imageData = wxImage1.GetData(); int imageSize = wxImage1.GetWidth() * wxImage1.GetHeight() * 3; m_sock->Write(wxImage1, imageSize); Is this correct?

Comment: m_sock->Write(wxImage1, imageSize) will send the data. Receiver can convert this data to image like wxImage( width, height, data ); So receiver need original image width and height. So you have to inform actual width and height of the image to the receiver.